# categorical feature in xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost, categorical-data

I tried to get more details on how xgboost handle categorical feature but didn't get much help from their documentation. A few things I have featured out:

1. xgboost only takes in numerical input, so we have to do the conversion of all categorical columns
2. xgboost has a parameter called `feature_type` for `DMatrix`.

My questions are:

1. What are the acceptable values for `feature_type`?
2. Can I specify it to be categorical? ordinal?
3. If xgboost can deal with categorical feature_type, how does it spit on categorical feature? Can it split `{1,2,3,4,5}` into `{1,2}` and `{2,3,4}` in one split, which is what a correct categorical splitting can do (I believe R can do it)?